# How to figure out $\frac{((k+1)!)^{2}}{(2(k+1))!} \times \frac{(2k)!}{((k)!)^{2}} = \frac{(k+1)^{2}}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ratio

$$\frac{((k+1)!)^{2}}{(2(k+1))!} \times \frac{(2k)!}{((k)!)^{2}} = \frac{(k+1)^{2}}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}$$

What is the method for figuring out this product?

What I can discern:

1. The factorial was taken out of the first numerator.
2. The second numerator was cancelled.

What are some of the rules for simplifying this?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{((k+1)!)^{2}}{(2(k+1))!} \times \frac{(2k)!}{((k)!)^{2}}$

$\frac{(2k)!}{(2(k+1))!} \times \frac{((k+1)!)^{2}}{((k)!)^{2}}$

$\frac{(2k)!}{(2k)!(2k+1)(2k+2)} \times \frac{(k!(k+1))^{2}}{((k)!)^{2}}$

$\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+2)} \times \frac{(k+1)^{2}}{1}$

$\frac{(k+1)^{2}}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}$

Comment: THAT'S WHAT I'M TALKING ABOUT!

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{((k+1)!)^{2}}{(2(k+1))!} \times \frac{(2k)!}{((k)!)^{2}}
&=\frac{(k!(k+1))^{2}}{(2k+2)!} \times \frac{(2k)!}{((k)!)^{2}}\\
&=\frac{(k!)^2(k+1)^{2}}{(2k)!(2k+1)(2k+2)} \times \frac{(2k)!}{((k)!)^{2}}\\
&=\frac{(k+1)^{2}}{(2k+1)(2k+2)} \times \frac{1}{1}\\
&=\frac{(k+1)^{2}}{(2k+1)(2(k+1))} 
\qquad\text{(this can be simplified a little more)}\\
&=\frac{k+1}{2(2k+1)} \\
\end{array}
$